Graph of a function in Latex
Suppose you wanna plot the graph of the following function n: R_{+} -> R_{+}, defined as
n(x) = [(1- eta) gamma x] /[ (phi x - theta)( 1 + beta + gamma) ]
where eta, gamma, phi, theta, beta are parameters that I calibrate as follows

gamma = 1 ; phi =0.5 ; beta =0.995 ; theta= 1 ; eta=0.75

The goal is to plot x_t on the x-axis and n_t on the y-axis.
The function shall behave as follows:

For any  x_t  \in (0, \frac{\theta}{ (\phi \eta}] the function has a constant value of \frac{\gamma}{\phi (1+ \beta + \gamma)} .

After that, the value of the function declines and asymptotically approaches the horizontal asymptote, which is equal to:  \frac{\gamma (1-\eta)}{\phi (1+\beta + \gamma)} .


That's my attempt:
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}          
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\usepackage{graphicx}          
\usepackage{float}              
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}



\begin{document}
  
  \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
              domain=0:5, % Range for x-axis
              samples=100, % Number of samples to plot
              axis lines=middle, % Place axes in the middle
              xlabel={$x_t$}, % Label for x-axis
              ylabel={$n_t$}, % Label for y-axis
              ymin=0, % Minimum value for y-axis
              xmin=0, % Minimum value for x-axis
              xtick=\empty, % Hide x-axis ticks
              ytick=\empty, % Hide y-axis ticks
              width=12cm, % Width of the plot
              height=8cm, % Height of the plot
              smooth, % Make the plot lines smooth
              axis line style={thick}, % Thicker axis lines
              enlargelimits=true, % Ensure space for the labels
              xlabel style={anchor=north}, % Center x label
              ylabel style={anchor=east}  % Place y label appropriately
              ]
              % Parameters
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\gamma}{1}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\phi}{2}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{0.5}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{1}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\eta}{0.7}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\alpha}{0.5}
              
              % Asymptotic value
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\asymptote}{\gamma*(1-\eta)/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))}
              
              % First part of the function (constant)
              \addplot[domain=0:1, thick] {\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))};
              
              % Second part of the function (exponential decay)
              \addplot[domain=1:5, thick] {\asymptote + (\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma)) - \asymptote)*exp(-\alpha*(x-1))};
              
              % Dotted lines for important points
              \draw[dotted] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,{\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))});
              \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,{\asymptote}) -- (axis cs:5,{\asymptote});
              \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,{\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))}) -- (axis cs:1,{\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))});
              
              % Label for max value (gamma / (phi * (1 + beta + gamma)))
              \node at (axis cs:0.5, 1.2) [anchor=east] {$\frac{\gamma}{\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}$};
              
              % Label for asymptote (gamma * (1 - eta) / (phi * (1 + beta + gamma)))
              \node at (axis cs:0.5, \asymptote-0.05) [anchor=east] {$\frac{\gamma(1 - \eta)}{\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}$};
              
              % Label for x = theta / (phi * eta)
              \node at (axis cs:1, -0.1) [anchor=north] {$\frac{\theta}{\phi \eta}$};
              
          \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Graph of $n_t$ as a function of $x_t$}
  \end{figure}
  
\end{document}



The graph of the function is fine except for the labels, which do not appear properly on the n-axis, and there are none on the x-axis:
At the maximum, the function should have this label:    \frac{\gamma}{\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}
The asymptotic value (minimum) that should appear as a label is: \frac{\gamma (1-\eta)}{\phi (1+\beta + \gamma)}.
The x-value after which the function starts declining should have this label: \frac{\theta}{ (\phi \eta}, but no label appears in my attempt.
Thanks!
Update, that's the outcome I get with my code:

** UPDATE 2 **
That's the outcome I wish to get


Please remove the about 90% of unused packages here: you impose a heavy download pain on everybody trying to compile your code … // It may also help to add a screenshot.

Sure! I do it immediately!

Here is one way to obtain:

In hindsight using pgfplots wasn't necessary here: plain tikz would have done all or most, too. The trick I used here is:

using pgfplots as a kind of framework
hiding both x and y axis later
drawing the x- and y-axis inside via Tikz

Let's walk through the code.
1. Preambel
As outlined before it's more flexible to create a separate graphic using class standalone.
Library arrows.meta provides many tips, e.g. {Stealth}. Replacing the standard tip by this one is set when the tikzpicture environment starts.
\documentclass[10pt,border=0mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},        % nicer arrow-tip
  ]

2. Axis parameters
I disabled as many as possible. min and max values are chosen, just to fit everything inside the bounding box from pgfplots. hide x axis, hide y axis removes the frame: comment both out and compile to see these layout related choices.
3. pgfmathsetmacros
It was clear early, that these names conflict with the formulas you want to put. So I renamed them with postfix c (constant). I also introduced a shortcut for the long expression \A absorbs now.
    % Parameters == constants, to avoid confusion with greek letters
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\gammac}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phic}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\betac}{0.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetac}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\etac}{0.7}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\alphac}{0.5}
    
    % ~~~ some constants ~~~~~~~~~~
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\asymptote}    % Asymptotic value
                    {\gammac*(1-\etac)/(\phic*(1+\betac+\gammac))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}
                    {\gammac/(\phic*(1+\betac+\gammac))}

4. Resulting simplifications
Your two plots now become easier to understand and to digest. // When drawing the dotted lines I put coordinates XL and Cl as these positions are needed lateron. You simply put a named coordinate or node after the point, omitting the \ (!).
    % First part of the function (constant)
    \addplot[domain=0:1, thick] {\A};
              
    % Second part of the function (exponential decay)
    \addplot[domain=1:5, thick] 
            {\asymptote + (\A - \asymptote)*exp(-\alphac*(x-1))};
    
    % Dotted lines for important points
    \draw[dotted] (axis cs:1,0) coordinate (XL) -- (axis cs:1,\A);
    \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,{\asymptote}) coordinate (Cl) -- 
                  (axis cs:5,{\asymptote});

5. Easy problematic labels
Placing them now is almost a no-brainer. Remember, by default a nodes position is at its center. To shift this reference point to the right node border, use anchor=east, which virtually shifts the label leftwards, etc.
    % ~~~ the problematic labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[yshift=-5mm] at (XL) {$\frac{\theta}{\phi \eta}$};
    \node[anchor=east] at (Cl) {$\frac{\gamma(1 - \eta)}
                                 {\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}$}; 
    \node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:0,\A) 
                               {$\frac{\gamma}{\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}$};      

Tikz-ing the x- and y-axis now is simple enough when you mastered the above. (For a more perfecet result you'd refactor the coordinates used in \draw ... because now you have to balance domain, min, max and these coordinates manually.)
6. Concluding remark
You could have placed the problematic labels with pgfplots, too; see e.g. what you can do with x labels, symbolics etc.
At one point it simply was easier to put some Tikz inside, as described.
To do the plots in plain Tikz, look for the plot statement in the Tikz-manual. The only disadvantage is probably related to scaling, which is not a big problem when you merely want a qualitative graph.
In general start simple, introducing refinement (e.g. for axis-parameters) only at a later stage, if at all.

\documentclass[10pt,border=0mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},        % nicer arrow-tip
  ]
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=0:6, % Range for x-axis
        samples=100, % Number of samples to plot
        %axis lines=middle, % Place axes in the middle
        %xlabel={$x_t$}, % Label for x-axis
        %ylabel={$n_t$}, % Label for y-axis
        ymin=-.05, % Minimum value for y-axis
        xmin=-2.5, % Minimum value for x-axis
        ymax=.27,
        xmax=6.5,
        %xtick=\empty, % Hide x-axis ticks
        %ytick=\empty, % Hide y-axis ticks
        %width=12cm, % Width of the plot
        %height=8cm, % Height of the plot
        %smooth, % Make the plot lines smooth
        %axis line style={thick}, % Thicker axis lines
        enlargelimits=true, % Ensure space for the labels
        %xlabel style={anchor=north}, % Center x label
        %ylabel style={anchor=east}  % Place y label appropriately
        hide x axis,
        hide y axis,
    ]
    % Parameters == constants, to avoid confusion with greek letters
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\gammac}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phic}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\betac}{0.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetac}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\etac}{0.7}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\alphac}{0.5}
    
    % ~~~ some constants ~~~~~~~~~~
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\asymptote}    % Asymptotic value
                    {\gammac*(1-\etac)/(\phic*(1+\betac+\gammac))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}
                    {\gammac/(\phic*(1+\betac+\gammac))}
    
    % First part of the function (constant)
    \addplot[domain=0:1, thick] {\A};
              
    % Second part of the function (exponential decay)
    \addplot[domain=1:5, thick] 
            {\asymptote + (\A - \asymptote)*exp(-\alphac*(x-1))};
    
    % Dotted lines for important points
    \draw[dotted] (axis cs:1,0) coordinate (XL) -- (axis cs:1,\A);
    \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,{\asymptote}) coordinate (Cl) -- 
                  (axis cs:5,{\asymptote});

    % ~~~ the problematic labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[yshift=-5mm] at (XL) {$\frac{\theta}{\phi \eta}$};
    \node[anchor=east] at (Cl) {$\frac{\gamma(1 - \eta)}
                                 {\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}$}; 
    \node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:0,\A) 
                               {$\frac{\gamma}{\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}$};      
                               
    % ~~~ tikz-ing the coordinate axis ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[<->]  (axis cs:5,0)    node[anchor=north west]{$x_t$} -- 
                (axis cs: 0,0)   node[anchor=north]{$0$} -- 
                (axis cs: 0,.24) node[anchor=south east]{$\eta_t$}; 
    
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}


Just for analysis.
There are some problems with your approach.

The 3rd \draw seems to be duplicate, as it's already drawn by \addplot. If you'd select other line parameters, you could see it. This way, by chance, the dotted line just doesn't superseed the thick black horizontal line already put.

At least your first node, (B) in my code, is drawn out-of-range. To better see this I uncommented most of your plot-parameters.


The other nodes will probably face similar problems.

The better alternative to my experience is to work with two separate documents:


for the/each drawing: using standalone class
for the main document: whatever you like, e.g. article

See the Semiconductors example for some code on this. You will gain more flexibility this way, and it will also be easier to cope with the out-of-range problem from #2.

I put node (A) by intention. Usually it's easier to remember a coordinate which was already calculated. E.g. you could easily introduce perpendicular intersections with point (A), see the tikz manual.




\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}          
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\usepackage{graphicx}          
\usepackage{float}              
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}



\begin{document}
  
  \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
              domain=0:5, % Range for x-axis
              samples=100, % Number of samples to plot
%              axis lines=middle, % Place axes in the middle
%              xlabel={$x_t$}, % Label for x-axis
%              ylabel={$n_t$}, % Label for y-axis
%              ymin=0, % Minimum value for y-axis
%              xmin=0, % Minimum value for x-axis
%              xtick=\empty, % Hide x-axis ticks
%              ytick=\empty, % Hide y-axis ticks
%              width=12cm, % Width of the plot
%              height=8cm, % Height of the plot
%              smooth, % Make the plot lines smooth
%              axis line style={thick}, % Thicker axis lines
%              enlargelimits=true, % Ensure space for the labels
%              xlabel style={anchor=north}, % Center x label
%              ylabel style={anchor=east}  % Place y label appropriately
              ]
              % Parameters
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\gamma}{1}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\phi}{2}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{0.5}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{1}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\eta}{0.7}
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\alpha}{0.5}
              
              % Asymptotic value
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\asymptote}{\gamma*(1-\eta)/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))}
              
              % First part of the function (constant)
              \addplot[domain=0:1, thick] {\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))};
              
              % Second part of the function (exponential decay)
              \addplot[domain=1:5, thick] 
                {\asymptote + (\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma)) - \asymptote)*exp(-\alpha*(x-1))};
              
              % Dotted lines for important points
              \draw[dotted] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,{\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))}) node (A) {A};
              \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,{\asymptote}) -- (axis cs:5,{\asymptote});
              
              % ~~~ this one seems to be duplicate, i.e. drawn by the firs \addplot alraedy ~~~
%              \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,{\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))}) -- (axis cs:1,{\gamma/(\phi*(1+\beta+\gamma))});
%              
              % Label for max value (gamma / (phi * (1 + beta + gamma)))
%              \node at (axis cs:0.5, 1.2) [anchor=east] {$\frac{\gamma}{\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}$};
              \node at (axis cs:0.5, 0.205) [anchor=east] {B};
%              
%              % Label for asymptote (gamma * (1 - eta) / (phi * (1 + beta + gamma)))
%              \node at (axis cs:0.5, \asymptote-0.05) [anchor=east] {$\frac{\gamma(1 - \eta)}{\phi(1 + \beta + \gamma)}$};
%              
%              % Label for x = theta / (phi * eta)
%              \node at (axis cs:1, -0.1) [anchor=north] {$\frac{\theta}{\phi \eta}$};
              
          \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Graph of $n_t$ as a function of $x_t$}
  \end{figure}
  
\end{document}


It seems, unfortunately, that labeling the x- and y-axes properly is impossible.

Don't give up too early. // It's very hard to read your intended labels from your code. I suggest you add a screenshot to your question, where you, using some bitmap drawing program, indicate the various positions and content ... at least for the most important ones.

As I already wrote elsewhere, at the moment it is very hard to tell which label, including its content, goes where (you may want to rework and clarify your question to obtain even better solutions). By your definitions \pgfmathsetmacro{\gamma}{1} etc. you'd display numerical values in those formulas once \gamma etc. is substituted. Not sure if that's the best way to communicate with the reader, here.
However, to help you overcoming the placement problems you still reported I'd like to draw your attention to ch. 4.19 Alignment Options in the pgfplots-manual: you can relate placement to various other parts.
A key is to name what can be named. Kindly see my example code below. A drawback, if it's one at all, might be that you may leave the cs-notation. Which in turn means: you can use polar notation for placing nodes, shifts etc.
Remember: unless otherwise stated by anchor statments, like I did below frequently, node positions are assigned to the nodes center.


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[                   % which parameters can be named, i.e. referenced?
        name=AX,                    % <<<
        title=hello,                        % not here
        title style={name=TS},      % <<<
        xlabel=x,                           % not here
        xlabel style={name=XL},     % <<<
        ylabel=y,                           % not here
        ylabel style={name=YL},     % <<<
     ]
     \addplot[
        domain=-1:1,
        %name path=CRV, % needs fill between
        %name=AP,       % no
     ]{(x-.2)^3 + 1};
     
     \addplot[domain=-1:1,]{x+1.5};
    
    \end{axis}  
    
    % ~~~ current axis ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=west,red,circle,draw]  at (current axis.east)  {CA}; 
    
    % ~~~ current plot ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[red,circle,draw]              at (current plot begin) {CPb}; 
    \node[red,circle,draw]              at (current plot end)   {CPe}; 
    
    % ~~~ named axis, see above ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=west,teal]     at (AX.south east)      {AX}; 
    \node[anchor=east,teal]     at (AX.north west)      {AX}; 
    \node[teal]                 at (AX.outer north west){AX outer}; 
    \node[teal]                 at (AX.origin)          {AXorg}; 
    \node[teal]                 at (AX.center)          {AXcnt}; 
    
    % ~~~ named styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=west,purple,draw]  at (TS.east)    {TS}; 
    \node[anchor=west,purple,draw]  at (XL.east)    {XL}; 
    \node[anchor=west,purple,draw]  at (YL.east)    {YL}; 
    
    % ~~~ EXTRA LEGEND ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-5mm,xshift=-5mm] (L1) at (AX.south west) {AX: AXis environment};
    \node[anchor=north west] (L2) at (L1.south west) {CA: Current Axis environment};
    \node[anchor=north west] (L3) at (L2.south west) {CPe: Current Plot end (linear)};
    \node[anchor=north west] (L4) at (L3.south west) {AXorg: AXis origin (cs: 0,0)};
    \node[anchor=north west] (L5) at (L4.south west) {AXcnt: AXis center (middle of plot)};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks so much for your time. I updated the question by adding the graph I wish to get
